# How to validate checkbox if the value was changed in inspect element - PHP

Tags: php, html

As the title says I want to validate my code when someone tries to change the checkbox value in the inspect element. But also to check if they remove the value in the checkbox. I can't imagine how can I validate this as there are many ways a user can check the box it can be ABC, BDE, etc. Here is my code to give an example.

```
<?php  
$letterError = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $arrayLetters = array('A','B','C','BD','E','F');
  for($i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    if(!in_array($_POST['letters'][i],$arrayLetters))
    {
       $letterError = "Invalid Letter";
    }
  }
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="A">A<input>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="B">B<input>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="C">C<input>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="BD">BD<input>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="E">E<input>
<input type="checkbox" id="letters[]" value="F">F<input>
<span name="error"><?php echo $letterError;?><span>
```

Comment: Try to keep record of , if 'click' event is fired on checkbox.

Comment: Not-checked checkboxes are not sent to the server so you should use something like `foreach ($_POST['letters'] as $letter)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_diff` to find values in the input that aren't in the valid list.

```
$invalid = array_diff($_POST['letters'], $arrayLetters);
if (!empty($invalid)) {
    $letterError = "Invalid letters: " . implode(", ", $invalid);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for thank you so much!